# My Linked List transversal and printing function does not print the last element of the list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

As the title suggests, my Linked List transversal and printing function in the following c code(print_ll) does not print the last element of the list, and instead, prints 0 and 1 in its place, to the console. For example a list with values 2 3 4 5, the output would be 2 3 4 0 1.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKJyi.png)

In this code, I have used 3 pointer variables. 2 for the construction of the linked list, in the function ll_init(dynamic_pointer1, and dynamic_pointer2), and the other one, in the printing/transversal function-print_ll(dynamic_pointer3).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


 struct node
 {  
   int data;
   struct node* nextlink;
 };


 struct node* index_construct;

 void ll_init(int s)
 {
   int ele;
   printf("enter the 0th element of your list\n");
   scanf("%d",&ele);
   struct node* dynamic_pointer1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   (*dynamic_pointer1).data=ele;
   (*dynamic_pointer1).nextlink=NULL;
   index_construct=dynamic_pointer1;

   int i, ele2;
   for(i=1;i<s;i++)
    { 
      printf("enter element %d of your list\n",i);
      scanf("%d",&ele2);
      dynamic_pointer1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      (*dynamic_pointer1).data=ele2;
      (*dynamic_pointer1).nextlink=NULL;
   
        struct node* dynamic_pointer2=index_construct;
        while((*dynamic_pointer2).nextlink!=NULL)
         {
           dynamic_pointer2=(*dynamic_pointer2).nextlink;
         }
      (*dynamic_pointer2).nextlink=dynamic_pointer1;

    }
   free(dynamic_pointer1);  
 }

 void print_ll()
 {
  printf("these are the elements of your linked list in order of their insertion:\n");
  struct node* dynamic_pointer3=index_construct;
        while(dynamic_pointer3!=NULL)
         {
           printf("%d\n",(*dynamic_pointer3).data);
           dynamic_pointer3=(*dynamic_pointer3).nextlink;
         }
 }       
    
 int main()
 {
   int size;
   printf("enter the initial size of your list:");
   scanf("%d",&size);
   printf("initialize your list:\n");
   ll_init(size);
   print_ll();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You are calling `free` on the last element of the list. You should instead `free` memory for the entire list when you're done with it (after printing them in your case)

Comment: thank you so much! I've declared struct node *dynamic_pointer1 as a global variable, and called free in the main function after printing the list, and it worked perfectly.